# How do I get the SUM() of every unique 'column'?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these SQL tables

Supplier

```
 SUPPLIERID | SUPPLIERNAME
 1          | sup1
 2          | sup2
 3          | sup3
```

Sold

```
ITEMID | SOLD | SUPPLIER ID | DATE
pen    | 10   | 1           | 2011-10-21
pen    | 5    | 1           | 2011-10-22
pen    | 5    | 1           | 2011-10-23
pen    | 20   | 3           | 2011-10-24
```

Bought

```
 ITEMID | BOUGHT | SUPPLIER ID | DATE
 pen    | 20     | 1           | 2011-9-21
 pen    | 5      | 3           | 2011-9-24
```

I'm currently using this script but it doesn't seem to work as the `SUM()` of sold and bought is tripled. I suspect the reason is because there are 3 rows in sold but only 2 in bought. Any idea how to fix this?

```
   SELECT suppliername, SUM(sold) as sold, SUM(bought) AS bought
     FROM sold s
LEFT JOIN supplier sp
       ON s.supplierid = sp.supplierid
LEFT JOIN bought b
       ON sp.supplierid = b.supplierid
 GROUP BY suppliername
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT suppliername, Sold, Bought
FROM Supplier sp
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SupplierId, SUM(Sold) Sold
           FROM sold
           GROUP BY SupplierId) s
ON sp.SupplierId = s.SupplierId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SupplierId, SUM(bought) bought
           FROM bought
           GROUP BY SupplierId) b
ON sp.SupplierId = b.SupplierId
```

Basically, what I'm doing is calculating the amount sold and the amount bought for every supplierId separately (in the `LEFT JOIN`s), so I always have the total amount sold and total amount bought. The querys that I'm using in the `LEFT JOIN`s are called derived tables, since they are acting like a table on the general query. Hope this helps you get a more clear idea of what I did.

Comment: It works, thanks! May I ask if you could explain what you just did and what does "derived" table mean? I got that error when I tried to removed s & b.

Comment: @JohnSmith - Ok, sorry, I added an explanation, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I'm starting to get it. One last question. I tried including the date in the SOLD derive query as well as the top SELECT statement and Im getting a NULL value when I execute it in SQL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JohnSmith - Sadly, I would need to take a look at your current query to give an answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I manage to solve it. I was "reading" the query the wrong way. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

From the given data I would expect to see the results for supplier 1 tripled, nothing at all returned for supplier 2 and the right quantity for supplier 3. This is because you are implicitly linking every result for each supplier from sold, to every result from each supplier on bought.

Instead, try:

```
select supplierid, max(suppliername) suppliername, sum(bought) bought, sum(sold) sold
from (
    select supplierid, suppliername, 0 bought, 0 sold from supplier union all
    select supplierid, '' suppliername, bought, 0 sold from bought union all
    select supplierid, '' suppliername, 0 bought, sold from sold) ilv
group by supplierid;
```